# Probability for integer random walk

Tags: probability-theory

Is there a way to construct the probability of the integer random walk without Caratheodory's extension theorem?

The integer random walk is the infinite succession of a coin toss, with probabilities $(p,1-p)$ for each face. So the universe is $\Omega =\{0,1\}^\mathbb{N}$ and we equip it with the product sigma-algebra, which is generated by the events "the $n$-th toss is 0" and "the $n$-th toss is 1".

Now I know how to construct a probability measure on this sigma-algebra by Caratheodory's extension theorem: the finite unions of those elementary events form a ring of sets, and the probabilities of each coin toss extend to them by finite sums.

But then Caratheodory's theorem seems a bit overkill for such a simple probability. Isn't there a more direct construction ? That might involve a more precise description of the sigma-algebra than just giving its generators.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Edit.** I didn't read the question carefully enough. What's below applies in the case $p=1/2$. Note the second construction can be modified to work for $p\ne1/2$; see below below.

It seems likely that any construction of this measure is either going to use the Caratheodory theorem or some other result that typically involves the C theorem in its proof. (As below, where we use the existence of Haar measure or Lebesgue measure....)

### Below ($p=1/2$):

For example, $\{0,1\}^\Bbb N$ is a compact abelian group, and the Haar measure on this group is the probability you want.

Or: Define $B:\{0,1\}^\Bbb N\to[0,1]$  by  $$B(a)=\sum_{j=1}^\infty a_j2^{-j}.$$ Then $P(E)$ is just the  Lebesgue measure of $B(E)$.

### Below below:

One can modify the second construction in a Cantor-settish way to work for $p\ne1/2$. Define $$I_0=[0,p],\quad I_1=[p,1].$$If $\alpha$ is a finite sequence of zeroes and ones, let $I_{\alpha,0}$ and $I_{\alpha,1}$ be a partition of $I_\alpha$ into two adjacent compact intervals with $|I_{\alpha,0}|=p|I_\alpha|$ and $|I_{\alpha,1}|=(1-p)|I_\alpha|$. Finally define $$B(a)=\bigcap_{n=1}^\infty I_{a_1,\dots, a_n}$$(or rather of course $B(a)=$ the unique element of that intersection) and set $P(E)=m(B(E))$.

Probably there's a simple formula for $B_p(a)$ as an infinite sum...

Comment: @V.Semeria Wasn't paying attention, sorry. See edit (in  fact it's clear that the construction at the bottom could be modified to work for a non-constant sequence $p_n$...).

Comment: This construction does map $\{0,1\}^\mathbb{N}$ into the real segment $[0,1]$, and allows to define the probability via the Lebesgue measure. But then the Lebesgue measure needs Caratheodory, and it is (arguably) even more complicated than the probability of the random walk.

Comment: On second thought, would $B$ be an isomorphism of measurable spaces ? It seems so. Then maybe the probability of the random walk is really equivalent to the Lebesgue measure, which would prove there is no escaping from Caratheodory.

Comment: "But then the Lebesgue measure needs Caratheodory":  I explicitly acknowledged that: "It seems likely that any construction of this measure is either going to use the Caratheodory theorem or some other result that typically involves the C theorem in its proof. (As below, where we use the existence of Haar measure or Lebesgue measure....)" Yes, $B$ is a measure isomorphism. Isn't there a general result about any non-atomic probabiility measure being equivalent in some sense to Lebesgue measure on $[0,1]$?